# Prevent people to submit a form with meaningless data

Tags: php

I work on a website which allows people to tell about how they were treated when they request for support from companies. The issue is that some people are playing with the platform using meaningless data like

```
blabla bal bla bka asdfdsff sdfs sdf
```

Is there a way to prevent this? 
Can't do the validation of data manually because the website is very dynamic with a lot of data. 
Thanks

Comment: Well... define **meaningless**.

Comment: Perhaps make sure that a highish percentage of the words occur in a dictionary.

Comment: You’re always going to be on the back foot with this. If people are submitting meaningless data, then don’t make the feedback request mandatory—people get frustrated and that’s when they put the crap in, as it’s the quickest way to get out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improve your form validation checks.

For the phone number, make sure it's exactly the appropriate size, and it doesn't (for example) have the same number (ie the number 0777777777 will probably be fake).

Calculate the letter usage in a sentence. The most used letters in the english language are e and a (I think). If the ratio is completely different (for example if there is no letter `e` in a 200 letter text - there is a bit problem ).

Also match the words with a dictionary. For a ratio of unknown words larger than 60% you can consider it to be not valid.

Check for dates, if you're expecting a date that's in the next few days, you shouldn't accept dates for 30 years ago.

Think of the data that you're expecting to receive, and find limits to it, that's the only way. Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no.

Long answer: you may want to try to match words against a dictionary. But this is not fool proof and when doing the matching too tight you may get a lot of false positives.

Another way may be to build a blacklist of bogus words and match against that.

Also you may want reconsider making that particular field required. When a lot of people fill in bogus data the form is probably setup wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it to an extent:

- Validation on certain fields (phone number, email, numeric/text only fields etc...)
- Restrict the user to use pre-defined items, such as drop-downs, check-boxes, rather than just plain text inputs where they have total freedom
- Run some checks through the dictionary and determine a desirable percentage of quality that a user submits.

Regardless of what you do, it'll never be 100%. The only (almost!) guaranteed method of correct validation with user input outside of pre-determined values would be to sit someone down and manually check every submitted piece of data. Even then, they're prone to human error and it still wouldn't be 100%.

My advice would be to keep all important fields to values you've already specified yourself with drop-downs, check-boxes, number spinners etc...

Add fields for 'additional comments' on certain items, but keep those fields unnecessary to the main process handling of a submitted form.